# Postgres query returns an empty array

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I am querying Postgres DB and using one of the returned values as a parameter for another query.

First query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT region FROM countries;
```

Returns:

```
Middle East & North Africa
Europe & Central Asia
North America
Sub-Saharan Africa 
South Asia
Latin America & Caribbean
East Asia & Pacific
```

```
SELECT * FROM countries
WHERE region = 'value from the first query';
```

Returns a list of countries with most of the values from the first query, except with: "Latin America & Caribbean" and "Sub-Saharan Africa", when it just returns an empty array.

REPLY TO COMMENTS:
I am actually using it via Node JS with Knex and React on front-end, but I tried to simplify the problem by doing it through pgAdmin.

My Node code:

```
// get Regions
const getRegions = (req, res, db) => {
  db.distinct('region as name', 'region as value',).select().table('countries')
  .then(function(countries) {
    res.send(countries)
  })
  .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error getting regions'))
}

// get Countries list based on region 
const getCountriesByregion = (req, res, db) => {
  console.log(req.params.region)
  db.select('country_code as value', "country_name as name")
  .where('countries.region', '=', req.params.region)
  .from('countries')
  .then(function(countries) {
    console.log(countries)
    res.send(countries)
  })
  .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error getting countries'))
}
```

Comment: Please show us the actual queries you are running in the second case.

Comment: Neither of those queries returns an array to begin with

Comment: `WHERE region = 'value from the first query';` makes no sense. The first query returns many values, not just one. So you can't use `=` with "the values from the first query"

Comment: can you please send request parameters which you have send to server?